# Should function return a customException or a String to hint that an error occured?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand what is a better design choice in the case when we have functions in a Class which does a bunch of things and should either return a string or raise a custom exception when a particular check fails.

Example :

Suppose I have a class like :-

```
#Division only for +ve numbers
class DivisionError(Exception):
 pass


class Division(object):
 def __init__(self, divisor, dividend):
   self.divisor = divisor
   self.dividend = dividend

 def divide():
   if self.divisor<0:
     #return "-ve_divisor_error"
     or 
     #raise DivisonError.divisorError

   if self.dividend<0:
     #return "-ve_dividend_error"
     or 
     #raise DivisionError.dividendError

   return self.dividend/self.divisor
```

1. What is better to return a custom string or raise exception especially in case of writing a python library.
2. And do we need to write separate classes for all Custom exception that we raise or is there a way to have an enum of some kind on a single customexception class?

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions. Almost 100% of the time the idiom in python is to throw an error

Comment: Ya. Also bcoz if I return a custom string and the function is complex I might have to do all those 100 checks to see what was the return value of the function - from wherever it was invoked.

Answer (score 1):

The more pythonic way would be to throw an exception. One of the python mantras is `EAFP: Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission`. If you look around the standard library, you'll see `try`/`except` all over the place.